# Controlling queue polling times

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus

I have a piece of code that pushes a message to a service bus queue every time a new article is added on my web app.  This then gets picked up by a `ServiceBusTrigger` with SendGrid output in my functions app that sends me an email that a new article has been added by someone.

This doesn't happen often at all and the only reason i decided to make it behave this way is to get my feet wet with some of the awesome Azure services.

My question is - since i don't really care about reeciving these notification email in real time... how can I reduce the frequency with which the trigger is checking the queue?

In my functions app's host.json I've already minimized the maxConcurrentCalls to 1 (default is 16).

```
  "serviceBus": {
    "maxConcurrentCalls": 1,
    "prefetchCount": 100,
    "autoRenewTimeout": "00:05:00"
  }
```

Is there a way to also set it so that my trigger only checks the queue every 30 minutes or something like that?

Comment: What's the benefit of reducing the frequency?

Comment: I wanted to do it to reduce cost.  I was under impression that if we check the queue every second or so the cost would be greater

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Message retrieval is managed by Scaling Controller, which you don't have much influence on, apart from `host.json` parameters that you have already seen.

To implement your scenario, you would need to switch to Timer trigger running every 30 minutes and retrieve messages manually from Service Bus, arguably losing many benefits of Azure Functions.

Update: You can now [integrate your Service Bus to Azure Event Grid](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/servicebus/2018/02/21/azure-service-bus-now-integrates-with-azure-event-grid/) and then use Event Grid triggered Function. Unfortunately, as of today it only works for Premium Service Bus namespace, so you'd most probably have to wait until they expand the feature to lower tiers.

Comment: Hi @Mikhail Shilkov,  could u share more about how message retrieval is managed by scaling controllers? which link did you refer to? thanks!

Comment: The info is somewhat sparse but you can see scale controller mentioned e.g. here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/event-driven-scaling#runtime-scaling