# What is the underlying mechanism to receive message in Azure Function Service Bus Queue Triggered functions?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues, azure-triggers

I understand that Azure Function - Azure Storage Queue triggered functions are triggered on a polling basis.

But cant seem to find how it work for Azure Service Bus queues. Does it also follow the polling approach or has a session with the Azure Service Bus queue client that gets triggered whenever a message is sent into the queue (something like an event-driven approach)?

Please refer to the following code:

```
[FunctionName("ServiceBusFunction")]
public static void Run([ServiceBusTrigger("testQueueDuplicateDetection")] string myQueueItem, ILogger log)
{
    log.LogInformation($"C# ServiceBus queue trigger function processed message: {myQueueItem}");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SerivceBusTrigger is also on a **polling** basis because of the underlying service architecture:

Azure Service Bus characteristics:

> is a reliable asynchronous message delivery (enterprise messaging as a
> service) that requires polling

[Source.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/compare-messaging-services?WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5003203#azure-service-bus)

However, [Azure Service Bus integrates with Azure Event Grid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/servicebus/azure-service-bus-now-integrates-with-azure-event-grid?WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5003203) (Service Bus will send events to Azure EventGrid when there are new messages) so this would prevent you from polling - if you switch to [Azure Event Grid Trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-grid?WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5003203) instead.

Comment: I see. But is there anyway we can customise the polling interval for servicebustrigger too? or it is a fixed mechanism?

Comment: See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/48899686/1163423

Comment: I see. Am I correct in understanding that the servicebustrigger is controlled by Scaling Controller which internally does polling and hence I could only control the parameters like maxConcurrentCalls to control the "polling" rate?

Comment: I think yes. Here you see all global settings that you can configure for the Service Bus binding - and there is no polling configuration: https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus?WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5003203#hostjson-settings
. But if you have a look at the Table Queue Binding, there is a setting to configure the polling interval: https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-queue?WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5003203#hostjson-settings

Comment: @MartinBrandl, for clarification of the emitting SB events to the AEG: *case 1:* immediately. if the SB entity is empty AND a new message arrives, *case 2:* every two minutes, if the SB entity is not empty AND there is no active listener/receiver.

Comment: @MartinBrandl yes I have checked those 2 linked before this, thats how I figured out that Table Queue Binding uses polling. But didnt manage to find anything of that sort for Service Bus Binding